# Browser getting 404 on all CSS and JS pages on Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

Rundeck: 4.8.0
RHEL 7.9
Install: RPM
DB: file

Rundeck started throwing 404 response on all css and js pages after I login. Not sure how and why this started to happen.

I am seeing these errors in service.log...

[2023-01-06T16:41:35,017] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/vendor/vue.min-5ecf19da2608574a2818739f14aaa804.js
[2023-01-06T16:41:35,024] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/static/css/components/theme-a881608cd0df3ed46ccec6d80d54f867.css
[2023-01-06T16:41:35,030] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/ansi24-57d7a35972a3170ed7697cf3bdf4a2f8.css
[2023-01-06T16:41:35,032] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/vendor/perfect-scrollbar-b4637c317b2f97ece10726ea6e3eb314.css
[2023-01-06T16:41:35,036] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/github-markdown-371020050d5a02d3e440c2a5d7b26057.css
[2023-01-06T16:41:35,041] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/vendor/jquery-ui-531fe4367a4266aaa1fa43972fa739d0.js
[2023-01-06T16:41:35,041] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/vendor/perfect-scrollbar-80c7dc9be9b25f4452390f63a8ca5f75.js
[2023-01-06T16:41:35,041] WARN servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET //assets/umd-vue-component-loader-c710398a6722b3283913530b8b784485.js

[404 respons in browser dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfy1X.png)
[page in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwiCx.png)

Rundeck was working fine and this started happening all of a sudden without any changes.

Comment: Is your Rundeck instance behind a proxy server? If so, set the `grails.ServerURL` parameter (on `rundeck-config.properties` file) with the exit Rundeck URL defined in your proxy server, something like: `grails.serverURL=http://mydomain/rundeck`.

Comment: I'm running the default RPM install of Rundeck so it's not using the "/rundeck" context.  This was working yesterday with the same configuration.  I have searched all over for the "servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GE" but have not seen anyone with this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you share the `rundeck-config.properties` file content to take a look? (Edit any sensitive info).

Comment: This was user error on my part.  I am using an apache proxy.  I added an extra "/" to my Proxy directives by mistake...

Incorrect
<LocationMatch "^\/((?!healthcheck|api\/).)*$">
    ProxyPassMatch http://localhost:4440/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4440/
</LocationMatch>

Correct
<LocationMatch "^\/((?!healthcheck|api\/).)*$">
    ProxyPassMatch http://localhost:4440
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4440
</LocationMatch>